# Cannot import name 'CallFunctionSpec' from 'keras.utils.layer_utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

the code was running fine yesterday
the code is:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

and the error shown is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-00e64660885b> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from sklearn import metrics
----> 2 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
      3 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
      4 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/saving/legacy/saved_model/utils.py in <module>
     28 from keras.utils import tf_contextlib
     29 from keras.utils.generic_utils import LazyLoader
---> 30 from keras.utils.layer_utils import CallFunctionSpec
     31 
     32 training_lib = LazyLoader("training_lib", globals(), "keras.engine.training")

ImportError: cannot import name 'CallFunctionSpec' from 'keras.utils.layer_utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/layer_utils.py)
```

it say it cannot import 'CallFunctionSpec' from 'keras.utils.layer_utils'
but i'm not using utils in it
i don't need utils in it what i need is layers but it shows error in utils

what should i do to solve the `cannot import name 'CallFunctionSpec' from 'keras.utils.layer_utils'`
and this error has been shown in multiple occurrences

Comment: Upgrade your `tensorflow` with `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you have to upgrade your keras and tensorflow in to the latest versions.You can do it using following command:

```
pip install --upgrade keras tensorflow
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

my keras version is 2.15.0
change --> **from keras.src.utils.layer_utils import CallFunctionSpec**
it work for me